# Why can't foreign key value be strings in my Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Foreign keys are saved as integers instead of the string attributes in my Django model. Why are they not string?

```py
class CreateRoutine(models.Model):
    createRoutineID = models.AutoField(default=None, max_length=20, primary_key=True, verbose_name='createRoutine ID')
    dpt_code = models.ForeignKey('Department', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='dpt_code',
                                 db_column="dpt_code")
    fac_shortName = models.ForeignKey('Faculty', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='fac_shortName',
                                      db_column="fac_shortName")
    batch = models.ForeignKey('Batch', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='batch', db_column="batch")
    section = models.ForeignKey('Batch', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='section',
                                verbose_name='section', db_column="section")
    roomCode = models.ForeignKey('Room', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='roomCode',
                                 db_column="room")
    crs_title = models.ForeignKey('Course', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='crs_title',
                                  db_column="crs_title")
    courseCode = models.ForeignKey('Course', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Code',
                                   verbose_name='courseCode', db_column="courseCode")
    day = models.ForeignKey('TimeSlot', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='day', db_column="day")
    duration = models.ForeignKey('TimeSlot', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='duration',
                                 verbose_name='duration', db_column="duration")

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"tbl_createRoutine"'
        verbose_name = "CreateRoutine"
        verbose_name_plural = "CreateRoutine"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually specify any field as a `primary_key`, text included. You probably haven't specified the `primary_key` for your models, so Django automatically added an `IntegerField` field for you; that's why you can call `instance.id` or `instance.pk`, even if you haven't added those as fields in your model. [This document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key) will be able to explain this point in more detail.

**edit/addition**

did some research and apparently you can store whatever field of the referenced model as a Foreign key as long as the field is `unique=True` 
in order to do this use `to_field` [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) attribute of ForeignKey.

```
class MyModel(Model):
    related = ForeignKey(RelatedModel, to_field='related_model_unique_field`)
```

I hope this does not answer the question directly but I'm sure your happy with it

Comment: Django model Foreign key returning id and not the string or character value of the attribute in database as specified in __unicode__. How can I save foreign key as characterfield instead of integer in database? Example - If  fac_shortName is foreign key it should be saved as character field and not integer in database

Comment: Well I suggest you opening your database in some db browser and closely looking into its structure. Maybe it will give you some answers.

Comment: Django - Return foreign key field in string method. How can I do that in code? I checked the database postgresql foreign key  is stored as integer instead of character varying field

Comment: should i use property or unicode to return string for foreign key?

Comment: edited my answer please check it - it will allow you to use your special field as ForeignKey value

Comment: Is there any other way than using to_field and unique-True ? Because  I already have data containing same attribute value in a table and now when I try to migrate it gives me integrity error as same value cannot be used more than once.

Comment: field must me unique - please read the links before asking yet another question, and yes you can do it just state the text field in your `related_model` as `CharField(..., primary_key=True)` and `make model(Model): ForeignKey(RelatedModel)` this way text is stored as FK but without `to_field`. Please mark the answer as useful as it may help others (and btw could be your answer if you change your existing instances so everyone has the unique value field).

Comment: can you mark the answer as useful so others also can you it when they have a problem?

Comment: I tried to mark, but it says you cannot mark your own post. You can mark the answer for everyone